# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null | But points to the element when I console.log it

Tags: javascript

When I console.log the *target.nextElementSibling* it points to the correct element.But I get the above error while I try to add the class of *".d_on"* to the *target.nextElementSibling*.

```
var ul = document.querySelector(".images");
    var img_li = document.querySelectorAll(".img_li");
    var pointer = document.querySelector(".d_on");
    var left = document.querySelector(".left");
    var right = document.querySelector(".right");

    right.addEventListener("click",function(){
        img_li.forEach(element => {
          if(element.classList.contains("d_on")){
            element.classList.remove("d_on");
            var nextElem = element.nextElementSibling;
            console.log(nextElem);
            nextElem.classList.add("d_on");
          }
        });
    });//end of event

<body>
    <div id="img-nav">
        <a href="#" class="arrow left"><img src="img/left.png"></a>
        <a href="#" class="arrow right"><img src="img/right.png"></a>
    </div>

<ul id="images">
    <li class="img_li d_on"><img src="img/1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li "><img src="img/2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/3.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li  "><img src="img/4.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/5.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/6.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/7.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img_li"><img src="img/8.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: please share html code

Comment: `forEach()` is a loop, `nextElementSibling` isn't guaranteed for each element being iterated. And any logged elements are possibly from previous iterations.

Comment: Try "debugging". Step through your code line by line. Add `console.log` statements. Add breakpoints. Examine variables.

Answer (score 3):

Add a null check for the nextElement

```
if (nextElem != null) {  
        nextElem.classList.add("d_on");
    }
//Note: nextElem!= null checks for both null and undefined.
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Patrick's tip, try to add a

```
if (nextElem) {
    nextElem.classList.add("d_on");
}
```